# Dynamically create DateTimeAxis QML chart SplineSeries

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qchart

I used to append using

```
 splineseries->append(i.key().toMSecsSinceEpoch(),i.value());
```

But x axis getting same value repeated .

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the format is extensive and they are overlapping, could provide a [mcve] and show a picture of what you want to get to help you.

Comment: Also I do not see any data and with a well known date of the year 70, so it makes me suppose that you are not adding the data correctly, or the dates you have are null.

Comment: Its a map. I is the iterator. Data and epoch is getting correctly printed on console.

Comment: I doubt it, if you do not provide a [mcve] I will continue to doubt it so the results contradict you.

Comment: I dont know why 1970 came. Actually I used 2018-05-23 and related dates

Comment: read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#details : *A datetime can also be set using the setTime_t() function that takes a POSIX-standard "number of seconds since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970" value*

Comment: ok .Let me check

Comment: We have to initialize datetime axis with proper  min and max . Otherwise it will be set to base 1970

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes  set min and max . Thank you for your consideration

Comment: You see, I assume that they had placed a range at the time, for me your question is of poor quality because it does not give us the necessary elements to solve it. Do you want us to guess?

Comment: Sorry  for asking with out necessary code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
splineseries->append(i.key().toMSecsSinceEpoch(),i.value());
```

will work . But We have set min and max values for DateTimeaxis  like

```
Xaxis->setMin(QDateTime(QDate(2018,01,01),QTime(01,00,00)));
Xaxis->setMax(QDateTime(QDate(2050,01,03),QTime(12,00,00)));
```